# Multiple fields to display from Access DB to simple table in asp page

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I need to have a series of tables on a page that each have a list of categories. Each category has a salary and number of respondents. All said and done, it should look like this on the page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk5Xa.jpg

My database looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQOz3.jpg

I tried this:

```
<% do until myResults.EOF %>
           <tr>
             <td><% response.write myResults.Fields.Item("categories").Value %></td>
             <td><% response.write myResults.Fields.Item("salary").Value %></td>
             <td><% response.write myResults.Fields.Item("respondents").Value %></td>
           </tr>
           <% myResults.MoveNext
           loop %>
```

...but this shows *all* of the information in the database. For this example I just need the ones under "byBusinessSector" to show in this table. (And yes, it is in classic asp. I can't do any other version at this time due to my company wanting this format.)

I don't know if built the database wrong by including information that doesn't need to show.

Maybe I should write my database differently? Or what if I made reference to the ID numbers instead? I'm not sure.

Comment: Databases do not work like that. Every row that is byBusinessSector need to say that and then you can select from the table `... WHERE section = 'byBusinessSector'`.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying I need to change the way the database is constructed so to get multiple values for a single heading. Do you have an example of this? I'm not visualising it.

Comment: No, I am not. You need to fill in all the rows. There is no such thing as a heading/

Comment: I agree there is no such thing as a heading, just names for the columns. However, there needs to be at least 13 tables displaying data on this page, and some of the category criteria has the same name, just under a different heading. I'll need to display two separate pieces of information for one listing. For example, line one will be called "Association" and have two items; a salary and a number of respondents. What method is used to display this?

Comment: What he was trying to tell you is that the "Section" column of your table does not have values for rows 2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10. You need to have the business sector in every single row.
Then you need to add the ... WHERE section = 'byBusinessSector' to your code